# Update multiple packages on Package Manager Console in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

In Visual Studio, Package Manager Console is faster than Package Manager Dialog, and that's why I always the console.

However, there are certain time when I need to update 2/3 packages at a time. Say, model + repository projects. Is there any command to specify these 2/3 packages at a time? So that I do not need to type and wait one by one.

By the way, I am using VS 2013.
Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can separate the update commands using `;` so it looks like this:

```
Update-Package <Package1> -version <version1>; Update-Package <Package2> -version <version2>; Update-Package <Package3> -version <version3>
```

This way you can just run it and go grab a coffee while it's updating.