# How to Update All Packages of solution to Latest Minor Version Nuget?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

Stick together with minor versions of updated packages, in the entire solution.

> Ideally Update-Package should do but that command will pick up latest
>   version of all packages, no matter what.

EDIT: I'm hopeful that there exists a switch, so that we don't have to type in specific versions of all packages one by one, NPM, where are you, can you manage DLLs as well ;-)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: yes visual studio.

Comment: Then right click on "Dependencies" in your Solution Explorer, then select "Manage NuGet Packages...". From there switch over to the "Updates" tab select the checkbox where it says "Select all packages" and then click "Update". This will update all packages to their latest stable release, including minor version (e.g 'v4.5.1 -> v4.5.3') Note: To do this for a whole Solution, right click on the Solution file instead of the dependencies of each project

Answer (score 21):

I managed to upgrade all my packages to their latest minor version by using the [dotnet-outdated](https://github.com/jerriep/dotnet-outdated) global tool like this:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated
dotnet outdated --version-lock major --upgrade
```

It upgraded all the packages in that folder without any problems of intermediary downgrade errors.

**UPDATE NOV 2020**

According to [Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/your-dotnet-outdated-is-outdated-update-and-help-keep-your-net-projects-up-to-date), `dotnet outdated` is `outdated`. Long live the `dotnet-outdated-tool`!

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated-tool
dotnet outdated --version-lock major --upgrade
```

Comment: Today I had some problems when using `dotnet outdated`. Even to the extent that the csproj files were screwed up. Then I realized that GitKraken was interferring with the process of updating these files simply by reading changes. So I had to first close GitKraken and then call `dotnet oudated`. This made it work without further problems.

Comment: Weird, usually for me it's the other way around and it's VS that has crashes or errors or breaks when I'm doing things in GitKraken (like rebasing a `.csproj` or `.sln` file, fun!).

Answer (score 4):

Command you are looking for is:

```
Update-Package -ToHighestMinor
```

Above command is available only within the NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual Studio (and PowerShell) on Windows.

There is other similar command (which which works in both VS and CLI):

```
Update-Package -ToHighestPatch

nuget update -safe
```

Please note the difference - first command will upgrade to highest **Minor**, but second and third commands will upgrade only to highest **Patch**.

Also take a look on `-DependencyVersion [Lowest, HighestPatch, HighestMinor, Highest, Ignore]` parameter, might be useful in some cases.

More details:

- [Update-Package (Package Manager Console in Visual Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-update-package)
- [update command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-update)

Answer (score 1):

Check out nukeeper to help out achieve this
https://github.com/NuKeeperDotNet/NuKeeper

Comment: This tool is no longer maintained

Answer (score 1):

While searching on this I found an open source dotnet tool which can update nuget packages on both .NET framework and .NET Core. https://github.com/NuKeeperDotNet/NuKeeper

You need to install the package with `dotnet tool install nukeeper --global` and then simply use `nukeeper update`. It can also automatically create PR if you use it in your CI environment

Answer (score 0):

On the command line using `PowerShell`

```
([xml] (Get-Content -Path ./NameOfProject.csproj)).Project.ItemGroup[0].PackageReference.Include | %{ dotnet add ./NameOfProject.csproj package $_ }
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the existing answers, which have been validated by the community? Please [edit] your answer to help readers understand what you’re doing and when this might be preferable.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use something like `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc -Version 2.2.0`
as described here [microsoft docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/tools/ps-ref-update-package)

for multiple packages you can easily connect multiple calls by ';' as mentioned in an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43260535/10985463)

Comment: OP isn't asking how to update a single package, but how to update all packages, and there is an easier way of doing that that I know of, but it only works in Visual Studio. P.S due to the [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) tag you should use a package as an example that is actually compatible with .net-core, like [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) one

Comment: just took the first example from the doc but updated answer anyways :-)

Answer (score -5):

Using Visual Studio, this is trivially easy.

Right click on your Solution file (or project depending on which you want to update) and select "Manage NuGet Packages...". From there switch over to the "Updates" tab select the checkbox where it says "Select all packages" and then click "Update". This will update all packages to their latest stable release, including minor version (e.g 'v4.5.1 -> v4.5.3')

Manage NuGet Packages

[image: Manage NuGet packages]

Navigate to Updates Tab

[image: Navigate to Updates]

Select all packages

[image: Select all packages]

And finally update all packages

[image: Update]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This will update packages to their latest version, not latest minor version. Obviously if the latest version is also the latest minor version, then it's ok. But that will often not be the case.